# PHP: Truncate text at word boundaries

Tags: php, drupal

Does anybody have the exact name of the function Drupal uses to turn the following string:

"Hello, how are you. Some more text."

into

"Hello, how..."

I.e. The function that's used to cut off a sentence after x words, and then add an elipsis. Alternatively, if anybody has a php snippet that does this, that would be great too!

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 6):

```
function getFirstWords($string, $words = 1)
{
    $string = explode(' ', $string);

    if (count($string) > $words)
    {
        return implode(' ', array_slice($string, 0, $words)) . '...';
    }

    return implode(' ', $string);
}

echo getFirstWords('Hello, how are you. Some more text.', 2); // Hello, how...
```

Comment: `getFirstWords('Hello, how are you. Some more text.', 10)`. You probably want to do a check that the string has been shortened before adding the ellipsis.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be `truncate_utf8()` in `unicode.inc`.

Comment: That's weird, since space is a ASCII char I don't see the reason for a custom UTF-8 function. Maybe you could paste the code snippet here?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/truncate_utf8/ no need for drupal_substr() and all that slow crap.

Comment: @eyze: I haven't had experience with unicode, but I presume the reason for a UTF-8 function is to preserve multi-byte characters where the second half might be 0x20.

Comment: Indeed, however that doesn't happen with spaces, the same way trim() can be used on UTF-8 strings safely. http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8#utf-8_safe_functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can use function views_trim_text($alter, $value)

view more detail https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_trim_text/7

```
$alter['html'] = TRUE;
$alter['max_length'] = 200;
$alter['word_boundary'] = TRUE;
$alter['ellipsis'] = TRUE;
print views_trim_text($alter, $output);
```

Comment: $alter can be grouped in array like in the example in first comment of this function