# Truncate a string in php without cutting words

Tags: php, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract a fixed number of chars from an array, just full words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519890/extract-a-fixed-number-of-chars-from-an-array-just-full-words)

I need to truncate strings when they are longer than 20 chars. Words must always stay together, so that this:

**say hello to my little friend.**

becomes this:

**say hello to my...**

instead of this:

**say hello to my litt...**

I set up this function based on a comment in a very [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara/80066#comment10194834_80066). The problem with this regex is that it removes the last word of the sentence (when there are 2 words or more).

```
function gen_string($string,$min=20) {
    $new = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/','',substr($string,0,$min));
    if(strlen($new) < strlen($string)) $new .= '&hellip;';
    return $new;
}
```

Can someone give me a hand with the regex? Thanks!

**Solution** by [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018582/alasdair) (with a few retouches)

```
function gen_string($string,$max=20) {
    $tok = strtok($string,' ');
    $sub = '';
    while($tok !== false && mb_strlen($sub) < $max) {
        if(strlen($sub) + mb_strlen($tok) <= $max) {
            $sub .= $tok.' ';
        } else {
            break;
        }
        $tok = strtok(' ');
    }
    $sub = trim($sub);
    if(mb_strlen($sub) < mb_strlen($string)) $sub .= '&hellip;';
    return $sub;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara) [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-php) [#3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270644/php-truncate-text-at-word-boundaries) and maybe more...

Comment: Try This Link, May help You...
  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function gen_string($string,$max=20)
{
    $tok=strtok($string,' ');
    $string='';
    while($tok!==false && strlen($string)<$max)
    {
        if (strlen($string)+strlen($tok)<=$max)
            $string.=$tok.' ';
        else
            break;
        $tok=strtok(' ');
    }
    return trim($string).'...';
}
```

See it in action: [CodePad](http://codepad.org/4sN9HpVN)

Or, using special chars (must have Multibyte String Functions installed):

```
function gen_string($string,$max=20)
{
    $tok=strtok($string,' ');
    $string='';
    while($tok!==false && mb_strlen($string)<$max)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($string)+mb_strlen($tok)<=$max)
            $string.=$tok.' ';
        else
            break;
        $tok=strtok(' ');
    }
    return trim($string).'...';
}
```

Comment: Note that since it adds 3 periods onto the end, if you want a maximum of 20 characters you should call it with 17 as 2nd argument. Or you could remove the `.'...'` in the last line of the function.

Comment: It should be pretty fast, it uses strtok and breaks as soon as you get to the end. It's also very memory efficient! Gotta save those bytes! ;)

Comment: found an error. when the last letter in the $string is at the $max position, it removes the word. Example: gen_string('sáy hello tommy',15) returns "say hello" instead of "sáy hello tommy"... it is 15 chars long so it should return the complete string. It only happens when using special chars. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I updated the comment, it only happens when using special chars, like á or ñ

Comment: Fixed, but you do need Multibyte String Functions installed. There are no excuses, you need that extension if you're dealing with UTF8.

Answer (score 6):

You could probably just use `wordwrap()` for this, right?

```
strstr(wordwrap($string, $min), "\n", true)
```

It's faster and cleaner than using a regex.

Comment: wordwrap doesn't play well with all utf8 chars (eg: chinese, spanish special accents)

Comment: If you want a mb wordwrap, look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#106088

Comment: ok fixed the utf8 thing, but still i get this error with your code: Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr()  --- it is strange, the number of parameters is correct.

Comment: The before_needle parameter was introduced in PHP 5.3 - if you don't have that, mix something with strpos and substr.