# Limit number of characters and put read more link

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I am using in place ckeditor with jquery drag and drop.
I want to limit the number of characters to 20 and put the read more link. 
Can anyone tel me, how can i do this.

Comment: Covered in this quesiton:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work inside your editor but does limit the characters when displayed on html page on frontend:

```
<html>
<body>
<?PHP 
$chars = 20;
$desc = substr($ckeditorcontent,0,$chars); 
echo $desc ."...";?><a href="#" title="More info">More</a>
</body>
</html>
```