# How do i change multiple characters str_split index to one line character str_split

Tags: php, string, split, character

I have this code:

```
$text = "12345678910";
$codebits = str_split($text ,3);
for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++){
  echo "$codebits[$b]yes";
}
```

which outputs the result:

```
123yes456yes789yes
```

How can I change it to be in one line? For example:

```
123456789yes
```

Comment: `for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++){
  echo "$codebits[$b]";
} echo "yes";`

Comment: Can you describe more generally what you need the code to do? For this example, it looks like you're saying you want to go from `1234567890` to `123456789yes`. So, do you mean you want to swap the `0` for `yes`? Or the last character? Or the tenth character? Maybe give a few more examples of input and expected output?

Comment: you don't need `str_split` if you want to just replace the last 2 chars with `yes`

Comment: Using `str_split` is absolute nonsense for this task.  Who upvoted this question? It is not well researched, and I'm hoping it is not clear so that the question is updated to better explain the task.  I can't imagine this question will help any future SO readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit String Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019285/limit-string-length) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332305/limit-number-of-characters-and-put-read-more-link and many, many more because this is a RTM question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like below:-

```
<?php

echo substr($text,0,8)."yes";
```

Output:-https://eval.in/896033

***Or if you want to use your one:-***

```
<?php

$text = "12345678910";
$codebits = str_split($text ,3);
for($b = 0; $b<3; $b++){
  echo "$codebits[$b]";
}
echo "yes";
```

Output:- https://eval.in/896040

Answer (score -1):

if you must use str_split:

```
<?php
$text = "12345678910";
$codebits = str_split($text ,strlen($text)-2);
$codebits[1]="yes";
for($b = 0; $b<2; $b++){
  echo "$codebits[$b]";
}
?>
```

And you can concatanate array $codebits:

```
$fullstring=$codebits[0].$codebits[1];
echo $fullstring;
```