# how to get an excerpt of some post contents

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page where i display all post coming from the database, I don't want to display all the contents just the excerpts from it. This is just easy i know, i could search the internet for it, but i don't know what you call it. Anybody can point me to the right road thanks.
BTW i'm using codeigniter for my site.

example of what i am talking about is:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**The Title**

sdfgsjdhfglksjhfdgksdjfhglskdjfghlsdkjfhglskdjfhgslkjdfhg(read more).

**The second title**   
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum(read more).
```

Comment: You could look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this depending on where you want to cut it off.

An easy way is to split the string with a space then take the first X spaces/

```
$excerpt = array_slice( explode( " ", $text ), 0, 30 );
```

This way it wont cut the text off in the middle of a word.

Comment: Oh , thank you, i'll be searching more on those string functions . . .thanks.

Answer (score 3):

or you can use the built-in text helper http://s.zah.me/KJXK6o and use one of the two functions `word_limiter` or `character_limiter`

like

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = word_limiter($string, 4);

// Returns: Here is a nice…
```

Comment: Yes, silly of me not to read the user guide, Codeigniter comes with this helper.. thank you for pointing it out