# How to save just the first 4 words in a string?

Tags: php, string, explode, implode

So basically I hard an extremely large string, and I would just like to save the first 4 words of it.

I ALMOST had this working, although there are some cases that break it.

Here is my current code:

```
$title = "blah blah blah, long paragraph goes here";
//Make title only have first 4 words
$pieces = explode(" ", $title);
$first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 4));
$title = $first_part;
//title now has first 4 words
```

The main cases that break it are `line-breaks`. If I have a paragraph like this:

```
Testing one two three
Testing2 a little more three two one
```

The `$title` would be equal to `Testing one two three Testing2`

Another example:

```
Testing
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
sdfgasfgasfg fdgadfgafg fg
```

Title would equal = `Testing test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 sdfgasfgasfg fdgadfgafg fg`

For some reason it is grabbing the first word on the next line aswel.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bit hacky but I would try just using a str_replace() to get rid of any line-breaks.

```
$titleStripped = str_replace('\n', ' ', $title);
$pieces - explode(' ', $title);
```

Depends on your application and expected data though. If you're expecting more than line breaks, go with a preg_replace. Either way, prep the data before exploding.

Comment: Good idea, although the data can be basically anything. Could even have 5 line-breaks before the next word.

Comment: Actually, this could work quite well if I use my method, but then replace the line-breaks with spaces, then use my method again

Comment: Ended up using your logic for my answer and I created a `preg_match` that replaces any linebreaks. For those who want to know how I solved it, I place this at the beginning of my code: `$title = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", " ", $title);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function first4words($s) {
    return preg_replace('/((\w+\W*){4}(\w+))(.*)/', '${1}', $s);    
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/965343/2701758

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested code):

```
//--- remove linefeeds
$titleStripped = str_replace('\n', ' ', $title);
//--- strip out multiple space caused by above line
preg_replace('/ {2,}/g',$titleStripped );
//--- make it an array
$pieces = explode( ' ', $titleStripped );
//--- get the first 4 words
$first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 4));
```