# Add a line break in Woocommerce Product Titles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title, product

Let's say my product title is:

> **Brown Colored Leather Shoes**

But based on my column width the title looks like this:

> **Brown Colored Leather**
>   **Shoes**

I know it's possible to do a character replacement so that a `"|"` in the backend becomes a line break `<br/>`. But I don't know how.

I want it to look like this

> **Brown Colored**
>   **Leather Shoes**

I found these references:

- [Adding a break to product title on shop pages for a certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224788/adding-a-break-to-product-title-on-shop-pages-for-a-certain-length)
- https://medium.com/@clarklab/add-a-line-break-in-a-wordpress-title-b3aeff346037

Is it possible to add a line break to WC products long titles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2020 revision** - *Still works on Wordpress 5.5.1 with WooCommerce 4.4.1*

Using this custom function hooked in **`the_title`** filter hook will do the job (replacing a pipe character `|` by a `<br>` in product titles):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_product_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_title( $title, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true ); 

    if( in_array( $post_type, array( 'product', 'product_variation') ) ) {
        $title = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $title ); // we replace "|" by "<br>"
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

> Now you can target different product pages with the WC conditionals tags as `is_product()`, `is_shop()`, `is_product_category()` or `is_product_tag()` *(and many others)*…

Comment: Nope. I must be doing something wrong :( https://imgur.com/ki1Avuw   Added to my child theme btw.

Comment: :( Yeah I see it works for you. Do you see ANYTHING that may look wrong with my screenshot? Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Ok I got this to do something!

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''<br>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/...../functions.php on line 450

Comment: I got it! The problem was a character in your code. 
The right answer is 


`//ADD LINE BREAK
function custom_the_title( $title, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true );
    if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' )
        $title = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $title ); // we replace '|' by ￼'<br>':
        return $title;
}`


Thank you thank you!!

When I copied your code it created an OBJ character. Here https://imgur.com/8expPVQ

Answer (score 2):

The full answer working as Nov 2019 with Wordpress 5.2.4:

```
//ADD LINE BREAK 
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_the_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true );
    if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' )
        $title = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $title ); // we replace '|' by '<br>'
    return $title;
}
```

Credits to LoicTheAztec and Coes

Answer (score 0):

I have a JS solution if anyone would like it, just add to custom js of what have you:

```
if (document.querySelector('.product_title') !== null) {
var str = document.querySelector('.product_title').innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("|", "<br/>");
document.querySelector('.product_title').innerHTML = res;
}
```

May be helpful if you need a workaround while you come up with a way to do it in functions.php