# Add a line break in Woocommerce Product category Name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a line break in the category Name with  "  |   "

For example, in the Picture that I attached.

The category name is : North American Red Sea Cucumber 北美红参

I want it looks like this: North American Red Sea Cucumber
                                                              北美红参
The First line is English and the second line is the translate.

I know it's possible to do a character replacement so that a "|" in the backend becomes a line break 
. But I don't know how.

How can I do that?

[Woocommerce category Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exxOc.png)

I found a [useful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412614/add-a-line-break-in-woocommerce-product-titles): [Add a line break in Woocommerce Product Titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412614/add-a-line-break-in-woocommerce-product-titles)

Thanks.

Comment: So is your problem solved now or? If it isn't you should show us what you have tried.

Comment: Not yet, I need to know WC conditionals tags for category name...

Comment: I tried this , but did not work....add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_the_title( $Name, $post_id ){ 
 $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true ); 
 if( $post_type == 'product' || $taxonomy == 'product_cat' ) $Name = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $Name ); // we replace '|' by ￼'<br>': 
 return $Name; }