# How to hide HTML in a Wordpress Product Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I referenced this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412614/add-a-line-break-in-woocommerce-product-titles)

And from that I used this code on my Wordpress Site

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_the_title( $title, $post_id ){
$post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true );
if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' ){
    $title = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $title );
}
return $title;
```

}

However, when I run it the product title line does indeed break but it leaves the 
 inside of the product title and customers cannot see that.
[HTML in Product Title w/ line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAJ8s.png)

I tried to add this:

< INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="
" style="display: none">

To the code snippet but it is not hiding the HTML from the product title. 
How would I go about inserting the line break *and* hide the HTML?

Comment: Having `<br>` in a tiltle is weird, because it mixes identification with styling, in my opinion. Couldn't you work with a sub-title or modify the container width so the title will break by itself?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that @Michael

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine on a clean WP install. Must be some other code that interferes here, maybe. The `</br>` seems to be html encoded in your example, and the title only breaks because there is no space for the next word.