# Add a line break in Woocommerce Product Titles and smaller font size

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using [Add a line break in Woocommerce Product Titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412614/add-a-line-break-in-woocommerce-product-titles/46412976#46412976) answer code, but i would like to change the font size for the 2nd line and to change the character from "|" to "-" but when i change it the code not working.

Comment: To change the font size you have to change the css, `$title = str_replace( '-', '<br/>', $title );` this statement will only replace explicitly given <br/> in the variable `$title`. Can help you further if you could post the html and css part as well.

Comment: Thank i actully took the break title code from you , the point im trying to replace the character from "|" to "-" i tried mayne character its all working except this character which i want it -
i tried $title = str_replace( '-', '<br/>', $title ); but nothing change

Comment: this is whit random character https://prnt.sc/upd6wf its working perfectly https://prnt.sc/upd7qh but as i explen before with - not working 
i used this code

add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_product_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_title( $title, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true ); 

    if( in_array( $post_type, array( 'product', 'product_variation') ) ) {
        $title = str_replace( '^', '<br/>', $title ); // we replace "^" by "<br>"
    }
    return $title;
}