# How to add a line break in WooCommerce product titles on static pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Here is a little follow-up to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412614/add-a-line-break-in-woocommerce-product-titles).

So in order to add a line break in Woocommerce Product Titles, I have added this code to the functions.php:

```
//ADD LINE BREAK  add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title', 10, 2 ); function custom_the_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true ); if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' )
        $title = str_replace( '|', '<br/>', $title ); // we replace '|' by '<br>' return $title; }
```

...which works amazing on Product Category pages.
However for some reason it does not when one of the product lists is imported as a widget on a static page (the Front Page of my shop).
What could be the problem?

Comment: perhaps your widget does not include the "|" character? you do need that <br/> tag in there. what does the innerText or innerHTML look like when rendered as a widget?

Comment: Can you verify if the `post_type` of your static page is either `product` or `product_variation`? Unless I'm misunderstanding your code, the replacement will only occur there. Try expanding the `if(...)` to include `$post_type == 'post'` if that's what the type of your static page is.

Comment: The post_type indeed is 'post', so indeed that makes sense. However no result when I tried to include it in the if, unfortunately.

Comment: InnerHTML would look something like this:

<!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
   <div data-block-name="woocommerce/product-category" data-columns="4" data-rows="4" data-categories="[23]" class="wc-block-grid wp-block-product-category wc-block-product-category has-4-columns has-multiple-rows"><ul class="wc-block-grid__products"><li class="wc-block-grid__product">