# Reduce product long description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-wordpress

I have found the following code [from this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161660/3730754), but it only applied under the product title. So how can apply to the detailed description of the product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shorten_product_excerpt', 35 );
function shorten_product_excerpt()
{
    global $post;
    $limit = 14;
    $text = $post->post_excerpt;
    if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
        $arr = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($arr);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
        // $text = force_balance_tags($text); // may be you dont need this…
    }
    echo '<span class="excerpt"><p>' . $text . '</p></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Woocommerce product single pages, the long description is displayed in the "description tab". If you look at the source code of `single-product/tabs/description.php` template, it use `the_content()` wordpress function to display that long description.

So you can use `the_content` dedicated Wordpress filter hook to reduce the product long description:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shorten_product_long_descrition', 20 );
function shorten_product_long_descrition( $content ){
    // Only for single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

    // Set the limit of words
    $limit = 14;

    if (str_word_count($content, 0) > $limit) {
        $arr = str_word_count($content, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($arr);
        $text = '<p>' . substr($content, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...</p>';
        $content = force_balance_tags($text); // needded
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Similar: [Limit product short description length in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155544/limit-product-short-description-length-in-woocommerce/38161660#38161660)