# Add a "read more" button on WooCommerce single product page description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a store that has long product descriptions and I want to truncate the description to show 100 words and then a button that says "read more" and "read less".

Actually I am using [Reduce product long description in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653135/reduce-product-long-description-in-woocommerce/50654957#50654957) answer code that can limit short description length by specific word number count and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a minor tweak to the existing code that instead of leaving out some of the `$content`, keeps all of the `$content` but shows only part of it until the read button is clicked.

Then it uses `jQuery` which has control over the read more/less button where either all `$content` or only part of it is shown.

**NOTE:** CSS (styling) and further jQuery adjustments are theme dependent. This answer contains the basis of a read more / less button. Each theme has different and specific requirements so further adaptation of the display/functionality must be provided by yourself

Explanation via comment tags provided in the code

```php
// Shorten product long descrition with read more button
function filter_the_content( $content ) {
    // Only for single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

    // Set the limit of words
    $limit = 14;
    
    // Strip p tags if needed
    $content = str_replace( array( '<p>', '</p>' ), '', $content );

    // If the content is longer than the predetermined limit
    if ( str_word_count( $content, 0 ) > $limit ) {
        // Returns an associative array, where the key is the numeric position of the word inside the string and the value is the actual word itself
        $arr = str_word_count( $content, 2 );
        
        // Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
        $pos = array_keys( $arr );
        
        // First part
        $text = '<p>' . substr( $content, 0, $pos[$limit] ) . '<span id="dots">...</span>';
        
        // More part
        $text .= '<span id="more">' . substr( $content, $pos[$limit] ) . '</span></p>';
        
        // Read button
        $text .= '<button id="read-button"></button>';
        
        $content = force_balance_tags( $text ); // needded
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
            // Settings
            var read_more_btn_txt = 'Read more';
            var read_less_btn_txt = 'Read less';
            
            // Selectors
            var more = '#more';
            var read_button = '#read-button';
            var dots = '#dots';
            
            // On load
            $( more ).hide();
            $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );

            // On click
            $( read_button ).on( 'click', function() {
                if ( $( more ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {
                    $( more ).show();
                    $( dots ).hide();
                    $( read_button ).html( read_less_btn_txt );
                } else {
                    $( more ).hide();
                    $( dots ).show();
                    $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 10, 1 );
```

---

[image: Read button]