# Show first 50 words

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have a long paragraph as a description, in the summary, I want to show just part of that, the first **50** words. This description stored in the database.

So how can I show just the first **50** words of this description?
I am using **Laravel 5.5.**

I call it like that:

```
<p class="text-danger"> {{$project->description}} </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I truncate a string to the first 20 words in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965235/how-can-i-truncate-a-string-to-the-first-20-words-in-php)

Comment: Try: `{{ str_limit($project->description, 50) }}`

Comment: Thanks, {{ str_limit($project->description, 50) }} This is work

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str_limit()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-limit)

Try like this:

```
{{ str_limit($project->description, 50) }}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It counts by characters, not by words. but it okay for me, thanks.

Comment: Glad i could help you! Accept it and close the issue!

Comment: @Gist Try this: `{!! Str::words($project->description, 10,'....')  !!}` Hope this is what you are looking for! But i think this works only in Laravel 4, not in L5. For now just try and look the result!

Comment: For some reason `str_limit`didn't work for me as the function has been deprecated [read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095567/limit-text-using-str-limit-function-in-laravel-5-5), I had to use `Str::limit` but I'll use `Str::words` (seems better for what I'm tryin to do)

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
 {{ strlen($project->description) > 50 ? substr($project->description,0,50).'..' : $project->description }}
```

Comment: It gives the same result as the solution accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can use

```
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($project->description, 50 ) }}
```

to show the first 50 words in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php):

```
{{ implode(' ', array_splice(explode(' ', $project->description), 0, 50)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model use

```
public function getShortContentAttribute()
    {
        return substr($this->content, 0, random_int(60, 150)). '...';
    }
```

in view use like below

```
{{ $article->ShortContent }}
```

Comment: this will give random number for ur pharagraph with 60 words to 150 words, hope this what u looking