# limit text using str_limit function in Laravel 5.5

Tags: string, limit, laravel-5.5, helper, truncate

I have been trying to limit my blog content text with `str_limit` that works fine until I apply limit of characters on it. kindly see what is missing in the code of my blade file:

`{!! str_limit($blog->content) !!}` works fine with the default limit, showing limited text on the view. But when I apply any custom limit i.e. `{!! str_limit($blog->content, 20) !!}` it do not show any text on the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have sorted out this thing using `{!!  substr(strip_tags($blog->content), 0, 150) !!}` , works fine with what I was requiring.

Answer (score 9):

The `str_limit` function has been deprecated,
but you can use `Str::limit($text)`[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-limit).

In the php code use:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

The sample usage in blade:

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($text)}}
{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($text,10)}}
```

Comment: this looks even better

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 7, all you have to do is open your blog directory in terminal and install "composer require laravel/helpers" without quotes.. after that, close your artisan and run php artisan serve again. go back to ur file and now you can use str_limit()

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 9 use {!! Str::words($blog->content, 1,'...')  !!}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).