# Call to undefined function str_limit()

Tags: php, laravel

Call to undefined function str_limit() laravel 6x
this my code , help me

```html
<dt>Description</dt>
<dd style="word-break: break-all;"> {{ str_limit($product ?? '',500,' ...') }}</dd>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limit text using str\_limit function in Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095567/limit-text-using-str-limit-function-in-laravel-5-5)

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5.4 upwards

Please use this like

```
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($product ?? '',500,' ...') }}
```

See Laravel [Tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-limit) for more info.

Comment: thx sir , i try this.
no i dont have error.

thank you sir for help and tutorial

Answer (score 27):

In version 5.8+ str helpers got removed you must use [Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($string)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-limit) instead

Try this one:

```php
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($product, 500, '...') }}
```

Comment: i try this, i get a new error, Undefined variable: product (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/tutorial/laravel_lazday/resources/views/admin/master/product/create.blade.php

But i , i fix in product $product to $product ?? '' 

Thannk you for help

Comment: @MasaliefMaulana I have updated it, sorry for the syntax error.

Answer (score 15):

Just install laravel helpers

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

[Repository](https://github.com/laravel/helpers)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution. I hope it has helped you:

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($product, 500)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_*` and `array_*` helper functions removed from `Laravel 6.*`
So try to use there class instead of global functions.

Or you can install https://github.com/laravel/helpers package to get both of these types functions.

Comment: While I agree that would be better to update the code to replace `str_limit(` to `\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(` the response from Hasan (aka `composer require laravel/helpers` would also make it work without update any code. Just commenting here since this was with an -1 before

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Laravel helper functions, you need to first install laravel helpers, using the following command:

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can do it in simple Vanilla PHP way...

```
substr($string_here, 0, 100) //100 as the limit
```

For rich text, we can do...

```
substr(strip_tags($string_here), 0, 100)
```