# accomodate html inside project

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have the following code, made in laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- basic -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- mobile metas -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- site metas -->
<title>Trabajos</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- owl css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<!-- style css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- responsive-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
<!-- awesome fontfamily -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body class="main-layout Recipes_page">
 <!-- https://webmobtuts.com/backend-development/creating-a-shopping-cart-with-laravel/ -->



@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Products')
@section('content')
<div class="container products">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{ $product->photo }}" width="500" height="300">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>{{ $product->name }}</h4>
                        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641254/call-to-undefined-function-str-limit -->
                        <p>{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(strtolower($product->description), 50) }}</p>
                        <p><strong>Precio </strong> {{ $product->price }}$</p>
                        <p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{ url('add-to-cart/'.$product->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-center" role="button">Añadir al carrito</a> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div><!-- End row -->
</div>
@endsection

<!-- footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class=" col-md-12">
                <h2>Contactanos<strong class="white"></strong></h2>
              </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  
                    <form class="main_form">
                        <div class="row">
                         
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono" type="text" name="Phone">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Mensage" type="text" name="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <button class="send">Enviar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <figure><img src="imagenes/inventario/bordado4.jpeg" alt="img" /></figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="footer_logo">
                      <a href="index"><img src="imagenes/Webp.net-resizeimage(1).jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="lik">
                        <li class="active"> <a href="index">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li > <a href="about">acerca de nosotros</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="trabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="blog">blog</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="contact">Contactanos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="new">
                        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
                        <form class="newtetter">
                            <input class="tetter" placeholder="Your email" type="text" name="Your email">
                            <button class="submit">Subscribe</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <div class="container">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- end footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the whole footer section appears down the shopping cart, I want the whole footer section to appear under the cart. the other way around it is currently. how can I achieve this? I'm not sure how things are accomodated in laravel. I've tried switching the order that things appear by switching the order of the code but thats not how things are seemingly accomodated. If anyone needs the css Ill post it here but I don't think its that necessary for what I'm trying to accomplish here.

[image: footer above cart section]

Comment: It's `<footer>`, not `<fooetr>`, maybe your styles don't apply

Comment: @brombeer done and done. what do you mean by that?

Comment: You might have a style that should apply to the `<footer>` element, but it isn't applied because you had a typo in that element. I don't know because we don't see your styles. Did fixing the typo do anything? If not, you might need to post the relevant styles

Comment: @brombeer no, fixing the typo did not do anything. Im not sure if I should post the style.css file, it is quite huge

Comment: Wait, you are confusing things up. If you are using `@extends('layout')` that is for extending HTML, to extend already existing `<head>` and possibly part of `<body>`... you do not have to write all HTML again, look for more tutorials about Blade as you are not using it correctly.